# Edit a row of Table in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I make a row editable by clicking a button edit. I tried put `contenteditable="{{stat}}"` and putting this code in `component.ts` but it didn't work

```
<tr *ngFor="let coll of colls">
        <td><i title="Editer le Collaborateur" (click)="EditColl()" class="ion-edit ion-white"></i>
        <i title="Supprimer le Collaborateur" (click)="DeleteColl(coll)" class="ion-trash-a"></i></td>
     <td contenteditable="true">{{coll.cin}}</td>
     <td>{{coll.lastname | uppercase}}</td>
     <td>{{coll.firstname}}</td>
     <td><a class="email" href="mailto:${{coll.email}}">{{coll.email | lowercase}}</a></td>
     <td>{{coll.datenaissance}}</td>
     <td>{{coll.dateembauche}}</td>
    </tr>
```

component.ts

```
statut:string='false';
EditColl(){
 if(this.statut==='true')
 {
   this.statut='false'
 }
 else
 this.statut='true'
}
```

Comment: With your code it should be `contenteditable="{{statut}}"`. There is no need to use quotes with `true` and `false` (then you can also use `[contenteditable]="statut"`)

Comment: yes I tired with contenteditable="{{statut}}" but I got no change the td doesn't become editable.. and when I use [contenteditable]="statut" I got an ERROR

Comment: What error? If the field that contains the value is `statut` then where's the point of using `stat` instead?

Comment: my point is whhen I click the balise <i> that contains  the function (click)="EditColl()" my row of table become editable that way doesn't help me

Comment: Your code seems to indicate that this is what you want. What is it that you actually want?

Comment: I can't get an editable row when I click on <i> .. evenif I click on <i> nothing changes

Comment: In your previous comment you wrote it actually becomes editable when you click `<i>`. I'd suggest you try to reproduce the problem in https://plnkr.co/edit/s7Z20v3gktsqRMIBKfDW?p=info